# How many integer solutions are there to $x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=n$. Is there a generating function for this?

Tags: diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, diophantine-approximation, theta-functions

It would be kind of cool to get a closed form for the number of integer solutions $$x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=n$$ which we will let $\phi_n$ denote.

It would be cool because we could exploit $\sum_{n=1}^N\phi_n\approx 2\sqrt{N}K(\frac{3}{4}) $ where $K$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) into giving us a representation of $$ \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\phi_n=2K(\frac{3}{4}) $$

This is demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946304/whats-the-area-enclosed-by-x4-x2y2y4-1?noredirect=1#comment6084924_2946304) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D+1%2F%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%5Csin%5E2%5Cleft(2x%5Cright)%7D%7Ddx). The general technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878934/a-nicer-form-for-sum-r-1m-sum-dr-1rd-d3).

I am not sure we should expect a closed form for this $\phi_n$ but we can maybe hope that we can use [something like theta series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837316/whats-the-connection-between-theta-series-and-the-number-of-integer-solution) to make the job easier to look at this sequence. In the link in the previous sentence I demonstrate how we can use the product of these theta-like series to give us a generating function for the number of integer solutions to $x^4+y^4=n$ and a wider class of Diophantine curves. The technique doesn't seem to me to readily lend itself to getting a representation for the number of solutions to the Diophantine equation:

$$x^4-x^2y^2+y^4=n$$

It's clear that $\phi_0=1.$ It's easy to see that for $n\neq0$ we have $8|\phi_n$. So if $x=a,y=0$ satisfies the equation then so does $x=y=a$. Likewise if the equation is satisfied by $x=a, y=b$ where $a \neq b$ then clearly it is satisfied by $x=b, y=a$. It looks for most small $n$ we have $\phi_n \in 0,8$. I am curious if there is a value for which $\phi_n>8$

Comment: I suppose we can make a type of claim from this alone we can say that 
$\sum_{n=1}^x{\phi_n}=O(x^{-1/2})$

Comment: How is the asymptotic in your comment possible? $\phi_n$ is integer valued.

Comment: @HansEngler. I maybe using big O notation wrong but isn't this just a reinterpretation of the middle equation in the question? The equation with the limit in it. I mean to say that as N gets large this sum $\sum_{n=1}^N{\phi_n}$ is approximately a constant times $\sqrt{N}$. 
Whoops. That comment should read $\sum_{n=1}^x{\phi_n}=O(\sqrt{x})$